# Disable importPackage, importClass and JavaImporter in Java Scripting

Tags: java, security, scripting

Can one disable the ability to import things from the classpath into a script in the java scripting API?
The goal is to leave the scripter with access only to what is in the binding of the engine, when the script is run. In some cases, importing random classes into scripts can be a security issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can overwrite the definitions of those functions and sanitize the script like this:

```
private String sanitizeScript(String script) {
    if (containsMoreThanOneStatement(script)) {
        throw new ScriptedPermissionsException("Scripts may only contain one statement!!");
    }
    return new StringBuilder()
            .append("function importPackage(a){ throw 'Cannot import!'};").append('\n')
            .append("function importClass(a){ throw 'Cannot import!'};").append('\n')
            .append("function JavaImporter(a){ throw 'I said, no importing!!'};").append('\n')
            .append(script).append(';')
            .toString();
}
```

This however still has the caveat that one can still do

```
java.lang.Class.forName('foo.bar.Zap')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to restrict all calls to the import functions then just null them when the ScriptEngine is initialized

```
engine.eval("importPackage = null;");
```